# Proof of $sup\bigcup_{i\in I} A_{i}=sup\{supA_{i}, i\in I\} $

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $I\ne\emptyset $, and $\forall_{i\in I}\ \emptyset\ne A_{i}\subseteq \Bbb R$, and $\forall_{i\in I}\exists\ c\in\Bbb R$ which is upper bound of $A_{i}$.

Prove that
$sup\bigcup_{i\in I} A_{i}=sup\{supA_{i}, i\in I\} $.

My attempt:

Let $A=\bigcup_{i\in I} A_{i}$

$c=supA_{i}\ for \ i=1, \ or\ i=2, \ or\ ...\ or\ i=i$

$a\in A\Rightarrow a\in A_{i}\ for \ i=1, \ or\ i=2, \ or\ ...\ or\ i=i\ \Rightarrow a\le supA_{i}\le c $

Now I'm looking for $a$ such that $a>c-\varepsilon$.

By definition $c$ will be $supA$ if

$\forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists\ _{a\in A}\ c-\varepsilon<a$

but a$\in A_{i}\subseteq A $ so $ a \in A$

Is it all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand this: $c=supA_i$ for $i=1,$ or $i=2$, or ... or $i=i$.

I would do it like this:

If either of the sups is infinite, the result is immediate. Otherwise

let $A=\bigcup_{i\in I} A_{i},\ c_i=\sup A_{i}\ $ and $B=\{\sup A_{i}, i\in I\}.$

We need to prove that $\sup A=\sup B.$

Suppose $\alpha=\sup A$. Then, there is an $a_i\in A_i$ such that $\alpha-\epsilon<a_i.$ Since $a_i<c_i$, we have $\alpha-\epsilon<c_i\le \sup B\Rightarrow \sup A\le\sup B.$

Now suppose $\beta =\sup B$. Then, there is a $c_i\in B$ such that $\beta-\epsilon/2<c_i$. For this $c_i$ there is an $a_i\in A_i$ such that $c_i-\epsilon/2<a_i.$ It follows that $\beta-\epsilon<a_i\Rightarrow \sup B\le \sup A$

Comment: But $\sup A<\sup B $ and $\sup B\le \sup A$ holds that supA=supB?

Comment: I proved that $\sup A\le \sup B$ and $\sup B\le \sup A,$ so they are equal. Which is the result we want.

Comment: You wrote "$\sup A<\sup B$"

Comment: A typo. I will fix it, thanks